# Proving a floor function is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a floor function $f: \Bbb R → \Bbb Z$,

$$
f(x)=\lfloor x-7 \rfloor
$$

That I am trying to prove is surjective or onto. I know by definition that the floor function's domain is the set of reals and the range is the set of integers. I also know how to prove a function is surjective, but in this case I feel like I have hit a wall. I don't know how to proceed from here, any help?

Comment: `I also know how to prove a function is surjective, but in this case I feel like I have hit a wall.` That statement would make sense only if it is reflected by your effort in the post.

Comment: @MathLover As I said, I know how to prove that a function is surjective (I have done some variations and examples from the book) just that floor functions are new to me and I don't know how to go about solving for x in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that a function is surjective, you need to prove that for each $y$ in the codomain there exists some $x$ (*which will depend on the value of $y$ and will likely be represented as some function of $y$*) such that $f(x)=y$.

Given some integer $y$, can we find some real number $x$ such that $\lfloor x - 7\rfloor = y$?

> What is $\lfloor (y+7)-7\rfloor$ for $y$ an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, just map every integer $x$ and you will get whole $\mathbb{Z}$.
For every integer $x$ we have:
$$f(x) = x-7$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
&\vdots &\\
   4 &\longmapsto & -3 \\
   5 &\longmapsto & -2\\
    6 &\longmapsto & -1\\
 7 &\longmapsto & 0\\
  8 &\longmapsto & 1\\
  9 &\longmapsto & 2 \\
   &\vdots &
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to find, for given $n\in\Bbb Z$ some real number $x$ with $\lfloor x-7\rfloor =n$, i.e., with $n\le x-7<n+1$.